# php - find DOM node and replace it

Tags: php, replace, nodes, domxpath

I would like to parse a DOM and find a particular node from a data attribute name.
Then I would like to replace it by an another dom.

I success to find the DOM nodes but I have some difficulties to replace it.
Here my code:

```
$content = '<article class="post-35">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="holder dark">
                    <div class="media"></div>
                    <i class="icon-play"></i>
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="item-date">July 3, 2015</span>
                <h2 class="item-title"><a href="">A title</a></h2>
                <span class="post-like" data-post-id="35" >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><g><path></path></g></svg>
                    <span class="like-count">2</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article class="post-36">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="holder dark">
                    <div class="media"></div>
                    <i class="icon-play"></i>
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="item-date">July 3, 2015</span>
                <h2 class="item-title"><a href="">A title</a></h2>
                <span class="post-like" data-post-id="36" >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><g><path></path></g></svg>
                    <span class="like-count">5</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </article>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes  = $finder->query('//span[@data-post-id]/@data-post-id');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $like = post_like($node->value); // '<span class="my-class"><svg></svg><span>xx</span>'
    $like = $dom->createElement('span',$like);
    //$node->parentNode->parentNode->appendChild($like); // this works but append plain text not html...
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($like, $node); // fatal error Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' 
}
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

When I print_r node I've got this:

```
DOMAttr Object
(
    [name] => post-id
    [specified] => 1
    [value] => 35
    [ownerElement] => (object value omitted)
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => post-id
    [nodeValue] => 35
    [nodeType] => 2
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => post-id
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 35
)
```

Comment: What are the difficulties you are mentionning ? Do you have any error message ? Any other visual manifestation of the problem ?

Comment: I've got an error on replacechild line. I have add the error in comment.

Comment: Well, it pays of to read the error messages: `Wrong Document Error`. You create a new node in a different `DOMDocument`, so you can't insert it into the previous one.

Comment: With the same dom I've got this error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the HTML part? And maybe `post_like()`?

Comment: It doesn't comes from post_like function, the output is correct. If I replace it with a strin like 'xxx' it doesn't works. about $content it several <article> wich several <div> inside it. it comes from a var to output with an echo and it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the full html?

Comment: Please see edit. But I tried with simple content and it's not working. My aim is to replace the span with data-post-id with another one which have exaclty the same structure but not the same text content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOMDocumentFragment appendXML method to add a "string" of nodes correctly to an existing DOM.

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $like = post_like($node->value);
    $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $frag->appendXML("<span>" . $like . "</span>");
    $node->parentNode->parentNode->appendChild($frag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the same document to create your element:

```
$content = '<div>.....</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes  = $finder->query('//span[@data-post-id]/@data-post-id');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $like = post_like($node->value); // return html string (<span>...</span>)
    $like = $dom->createElement('span',$like);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($like, $node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it was my first try but I have an error with your code: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'...

Comment: I edited my question and add a print of the node inside the foreach loop. It seems that the parentNode is missing but I don't know why...